# Class method with heterogeneous recursive infinite and dependent type argument

Tags: haskell, recursion, dependent-type

I'm stuck playing with *"heterogeneous recursive infinite type"* (some better title?).

Let the next working *"Deep Sort"*

```
class Ord f => DeepSort f where
  deepSort :: f -> f
  deepSort = id

instance DeepSort Int where
-- and so on ...

instance DeepSort a => DeepSort [a] where
  deepSort = sort . map deepSort
instance DeepSort a => DeepSort (Maybe a) where
  deepSort = fmap deepSort
-- and so on ...
```

for example

```
sample :: [Maybe [[Int]]]
sample = [ Just [[5, 3, 7, 1], [6, 0]]
         , Nothing
         , Just [[8, -1], []]
         ]

main = print $ deepSort sample
```

writes

```
[Nothing,Just [[],[-1,8]],Just [[0,6],[1,3,5,7]]]
```

but now I wish to parametrize sort criteria, to do some like (**not working**)

```
main = print $ deepSortBy sample
                          ( By   (compare `on` someCriteria1)
                          $ By   (compare `on` someCriteria2)
                          $ By   (compare `on` someCriteria3)
                          $ Then (compare `on` someCriteria4)
                          )
```

my problem is how to define the *"heterogeneous recursive infinite type"* argument (or whatever name be).

I think it is

```
By (f1 (f2 ... (fN a) ...)
   (By (f2 ... (fN a) ...)
       ...
               Then (fN a)
   )
```

Note: on `deepSort` example, nested containers was sorted ascending with default `Ord` instance; the sense of `deepSortBy` is to provide explicit `Ord` comparisson functions for each nested container. Since containers are `f1 (f2 (f3 ... (fN a)...)` then, criteria could/should be provided as `By comparer1 (By comparer2 (By ...`. But may be better other approach, of course.

moreover, probably exists a better *"Haskell approach"* **BUT** I wish (if possible)

- Exists some direct solution to my *"by class"* approach?
- What is the better *"Haskell approach"* to this kind problem?
- Some library solving this?

Thank you!!!

**EDITED**

I've a possible solution approach (post as solution, it's works! :D )

Comment: Could you clarify your example a bit? See, your `sample` is a list of `Maybe`s; so, when you (deep)sort it, you have to compare those `Maybe`s - but you start by comparing by `length`.

Comment: @MigMit you can see `deepSort` is to `Data.List.sort` as `deepSortBy` is to `Data.List.sortBy` (but instead using only lists, generalizing using a `class`). Also, `deepSortBy` could be written as `map deepSortBy . sortBy f` (with different result) but is not the main matter. I've added a note clarifying it (I wish).

Comment: How are `By` and `Then` defined? If you are having trouble figuring out what their types are, you should at least be able to figure out the types of `someCriteria1`, `someCriteria2`, `someCriteria3`, and `someCriteria4`.

Comment: @Cirdec really I don't know, I edited my question adding a possible approach (using `newtype` for infinite type) buts fail... :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any structure that can be [traversed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html) can be sorted. Both `Maybe` and `[]` are `Traversable`. We can capture the idea that all `Traversable` `Functor`s can be sorted by something with the following definition of `sortBy`. It works by listing all the data in the structure, sorting that list, then traversing the structure left to right, replacing each item with the first item in the list and carrying the remainder of the list across.

```
import qualified Data.List as List

import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

sortBy :: Traversable f => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> f a -> f a
sortBy o f = snd . mapAccumL (\(h:t) _ -> (t, h)) sorted $ f
    where
        sorted = List.sortBy o . toList $ f
```

When you `deepSortBy` something, you are simply applying a function inside the `Traversable` `Functor` before sorting it. It's just a convenience function that captures this pattern.

```
deepSortBy :: Traversable f => (b -> b -> Ordering) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
deepSortBy o f = sortBy o . fmap f
```

We can conveniently write sorting your sample in terms of `deepSortBy`.

```
sample :: [Maybe [[Int]]]
sample = [ Just [[5, 3, 7, 1], [6, 0]]
         , Nothing
         , Just [[8, -1], []]
         ]

sampleSorter :: [Maybe [[Int]]] -> [Maybe [[Int]]]
sampleSorter = 
    deepSortBy (compare `on` isJust) $
    deepSortBy (compare `on` length) $
    deepSortBy (compare `on` listToMaybe) $
    sortBy compare
```

The last line, `sortBy compare`, is equivalent to `deepSortBy compare id`. `listToMaybe` avoids the error that `head` would throw.

#### Reuse deeper comparions to break ties

Note that this doesn't reuse the deeper comparison to break ties in the outer comparions. For example, `sample` is sorted to

```
[Nothing,Just [[0,6],[1,3,5,7]],Just [[],[-1,8]]]
```

`Just [[0,6],[1,3,5,7]]` and `Just [[],[-1,8]]` tie when compared on `isJust`, and `[[0,6],[1,3,5,7]]` and `[[],[-1,8]]` tie when compared on `length`. If inner comparisons were used to break the these ties, `listToMaybe` would have put these in the opposite order. If the desired result is

```
[Nothing,Just [[],[-1,8]],Just [[0,6],[1,3,5,7]]]
```

we'd have to do a little more work to capture the inner comparisons.

Comment: Perfect @Cirdec! I was looking for a `class` (although ugly) solution but your solution is exactly I was looking for. Thks! On the other hand, `class` based solution can avoid `from/to List` conversion. Can your version work around that?

Comment: @josejuan If you add a `class Sortable f where sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> f a -> f a` then you can make instances for it specialized for `[]` ( `sortBy = List.sortBy`) or `Maybe` (`sortBy = const id`). Then you'd replace the `Traversable f` constraint with `Functor f, Sortable f`, or just `Sortable f` if you decide everything `Sortable` should also be `Traversable`, `Foldable`, or a `Functor`.

Comment: I note all of this should also work with `lens` Traversals... *cackles madly...*

Comment: Looking more seriously at this, the `partsOf` combinator seems to make this very easy: `deepSortByOf t o f = partsOf t %~ sortBy o . map f`